# Visual Studio Team Services Avoid 2 Builds to Test

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to keep our build time low for a new VSTS deployment, but I've run into an issue: I want to do gated deployments where both build and test need to be successful for the deploy to run, but due to our infrastructure I need to use msbuild with the deploy flag.

The current build step uses the flags: `/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="$(PublishProfileName)" /p:Username=$(UserName);Password=$(Password) /p:EnableMSDeployAppOffline=true`

Current Architecture:

```
Step 1: Nuget Restore (3s)

Step 2: Build/Deploy Solution (50s)

Step 3: Other Deploy Tasks (102s)
```

Desired Architecture:

```
Step 1: Nuget Restore

Step 2: Build Solution

Step 3: Run Tests

Step 4: Deploy built solution

Step 5: Other Deploy Tasks
```

Basically I don't want to incur that 50s twice where I don't need to, but I don't know what msbuild is doing differently when using flag /p:DeployOnBuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of /p:DeployOnBuild is indicate to deploy project after succeed build. No different between build, then publish/deploy.

For step 4, it won’t take 50s extra time to build, it will check whether the files are modified or not, if not, the result is up-to-date, this means it won’t build your project again, so 50s extra time is not needed. Don’t worry about it. Make sure the configuration and platform are same.

On the other hand, baywet’s suggestion is pretty good, split 4 and 5 steps to release.

Comment: Well, guess that makes me a fool! If I'd just tried it, it would have worked just fine!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should split steps 4 and 5 of desired architecture to a release definition.
Not only this is a best practice, it'd also allow you to have the second part firing only when build (steps 1, 2 and 3) is successful thus saving you time.
You can configure the release to trigger automatically when build is successful to avoid manual triggers and save time.
Also maybe you could split your tests between two tests projects/categories allowing you to fine tune your tests tasks targeting only what you need to target at the moment you need it.
Hope that helps